# databricks spark cosmos driver causing cosmos view failure due to field name

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

Using **com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-4_2-12:4.23.0** driver to create a cosmos view in databricks notebook.  The cosmos connection info are setup in Spark Config settings.  The view will get created, but will fail when trying to use it.

```
    Create or Replace Table cosmosCatalogX.CosmosDBX.ContainerX_TableNameX
    (
      id string,
      PartitionKey string,
      NumField int,
      `13D` string,
      ModifiedTS timestamp
    )
    USING cosmos.oltp
    TBLPROPERTIES(isCosmosView = 'True')
    OPTIONS (
    spark.cosmos.database = 'CosmosDBX',
    spark.cosmos.container = 'ContainerX',
    spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled = 'False',
    spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.includeSystemProperties = 'False',
    spark.cosmos.read.partitioning.strategy = 'Restrictive')
```

The second to last field '13D' seems to be the problem.
  The error states
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near ','.(line 1, pos xxxx) which points to the 13D field name position.
Since 13D can be interpreted as a double value (The D at the end of 13D used as a double type cast), the driver seems to be getting confused.
The real problem is that after the exception occurs every Cosmos view created under this catalog will fail with the exact same [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] exception.

If anyone has come across this issue and have a solution to be able the use such field names (i.e. 13D), I would appreciate your help.

Btw, the reason the Cosmos view is created as a Databricks table is so there is a definitive structure on top of the Cosmos Json documents for fields that may not be populated in all documents.  Otherwise querying a field that do not exist in the resulting documents (But exists in other documents) will throw the exception in Spark using the Cosmos view [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION].